# Hyperledger fabric instantiate timeout .npm ERR! network timeout at: https://registry.npmjs.org

Tags: node.js, docker, hyperledger-fabric

I wish to instantiate javascript smart contract base on raft consensus on Docker Swarm, instantiation is not sucessful.
docker logs says

> 2020-08-28 08:48:35.842 UTC [chaincode.platform] func1 -> ERRO 04c
> Failed to generate platform-specific docker build: Error returned from
> build: 1 "npm WARN xiotnet-js@0.0.1 No repository field.
>
> npm ERR! network timeout at:
> https://registry.npmjs.org/colors/-/colors-1.0.3.tgz
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: npm ERR!
> /root/.npm/_logs/2020-08-28T08_38_12_503Z-debug.log

In fact, fabcar javascript smart contract also
when I try first-network  (which uses solo consensus)，the contract can instantiate successfully.
when I try instantiate fabcar go version smart contract on raft consensus on Docker Swarm.
instantiation is also successful. but instantiating fabcar javascript smart contract failed and docker logs also similarly says "npm ERR! network timeout at:

> [https://registry.npmjs.org/colors/-/colors-1.0.3.tgz"。](https://registry.npmjs.org/colors/-/colors-1.0.3.tgz%22%E3%80%82)

next, I reproduce steps:

Step 1: Form an Overlay Network with Docker Swarm
[image: Raft-based First Network deployed in 2-host environment.]

host1 and host2 form docker swarm
[image: docker swarm composed by two hosts]

> docker network create --attachable --driver overlay first-network

Finally I add an overlay first-network, which will be external network(first-network) in byfn.
[image: overlay network]

Step 2: Prepare Fabric Network Material in Host 1 and Copy to Others

> cd fabric-samples
> mkdir 10.100.251.218
> cd 10.100.251.218

We copy directly the crypto-config.yaml and configtx.yaml files from first-network.

> cp ../first-network/crypto-config.yaml .
> cp ../first-network/configtx.yaml .

Then we generate the required material.

> ../bin/cryptogen generate --config=./crypto-config.yaml
> export FABRIC_CFG_PATH=$PWD
> mkdir channel-artifacts
>
> ../bin/configtxgen -profile SampleMultiNodeEtcdRaft -outputBlock
> ./channel-artifacts/genesis.block
>
> ../bin/configtxgen -profile TwoOrgsChannel -outputCreateChannelTx
> ./channel-artifacts/channel.tx  -channelID mychannel
> ../bin/configtxgen -profile TwoOrgsChannel -outputAnchorPeersUpdate
> ./channel-artifacts/Org1MSPanchors.tx -channelID mychannel -asOrg
> Org1MSP
> ../bin/configtxgen -profile TwoOrgsChannel -outputAnchorPeersUpdate
> ./channel-artifacts/Org2MSPanchors.tx -channelID mychannel -asOrg
> Org2MSP

Now we are preparing docker-compose files for all hosts. We largely base what we have in First-Network, with proper modification. We are creating four files here.

> base/peer-base.yaml
> base/docker-compose-peer.yaml
> 10.100.251.218.yaml
> 10.100.251.219.yaml

base/peer-base.yaml

```
    version: '2'

services:
  peer-base:
    image: hyperledger/fabric-peer:$IMAGE_TAG
    environment:
      - CORE_VM_ENDPOINT=unix:///host/var/run/docker.sock
      # the following setting starts chaincode containers on the same
      # bridge network as the peers
      # https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/
      ##- CORE_VM_DOCKER_HOSTCONFIG_NETWORKMODE=${COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME}_byfn
      - CORE_VM_DOCKER_HOSTCONFIG_NETWORKMODE=first-network
      - FABRIC_LOGGING_SPEC=INFO
      #- FABRIC_LOGGING_SPEC=DEBUG
      - CORE_PEER_TLS_ENABLED=true
      - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_USELEADERELECTION=true
      - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_ORGLEADER=false
      - CORE_PEER_PROFILE_ENABLED=true
      - CORE_PEER_TLS_CERT_FILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric/tls/server.crt
      - CORE_PEER_TLS_KEY_FILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric/tls/server.key
      - CORE_PEER_TLS_ROOTCERT_FILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric/tls/ca.crt
      - CORE_VM_DOCKER_ATTACHSTDOUT=true
    working_dir: /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer
    command: peer node start

  orderer-base:
    image: hyperledger/fabric-orderer:$IMAGE_TAG
    environment:
      - FABRIC_LOGGING_SPEC=INFO
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_LISTENADDRESS=0.0.0.0
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_GENESISMETHOD=file
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_GENESISFILE=/var/hyperledger/orderer/orderer.genesis.block
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_LOCALMSPID=OrdererMSP
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_LOCALMSPDIR=/var/hyperledger/orderer/msp
      # enabled TLS
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_TLS_ENABLED=true
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_TLS_PRIVATEKEY=/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls/server.key
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_TLS_CERTIFICATE=/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls/server.crt
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_TLS_ROOTCAS=[/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls/ca.crt]
      - ORDERER_KAFKA_TOPIC_REPLICATIONFACTOR=1
      - ORDERER_KAFKA_VERBOSE=true
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_CLUSTER_CLIENTCERTIFICATE=/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls/server.crt
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_CLUSTER_CLIENTPRIVATEKEY=/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls/server.key
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_CLUSTER_ROOTCAS=[/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls/ca.crt]
    working_dir: /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric
    command: orderer
```

base/docker-compose-base.yaml

```
version: '2'

services:

  orderer.example.com:
    container_name: orderer.example.com
    extends:
      file: peer-base.yaml
      service: orderer-base
    volumes:
        - ../channel-artifacts/genesis.block:/var/hyperledger/orderer/orderer.genesis.block
        - ../crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer.example.com/msp:/var/hyperledger/orderer/msp
        - ../crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer.example.com/tls/:/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls
        - orderer.example.com:/var/hyperledger/production/orderer
    ports:
      - 7050:7050

  peer0.org1.example.com:
    container_name: peer0.org1.example.com
    extends:
      file: peer-base.yaml
      service: peer-base
    environment:
      - CORE_PEER_ID=peer0.org1.example.com
      - CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=peer0.org1.example.com:7051
      - CORE_PEER_LISTENADDRESS=0.0.0.0:7051
      - CORE_PEER_CHAINCODEADDRESS=peer0.org1.example.com:7052
      - CORE_PEER_CHAINCODELISTENADDRESS=0.0.0.0:7052
      - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_BOOTSTRAP=peer1.org1.example.com:8051
      - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_EXTERNALENDPOINT=peer0.org1.example.com:7051
      - CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=Org1MSP
    volumes:
        - /var/run/:/host/var/run/
        - ../crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer0.org1.example.com/msp:/etc/hyperledger/fabric/msp
        - ../crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer0.org1.example.com/tls:/etc/hyperledger/fabric/tls
        - peer0.org1.example.com:/var/hyperledger/production
    ports:
      - 7051:7051
  peer1.org1.example.com:
    container_name: peer1.org1.example.com
    extends:
      file: peer-base.yaml
      service: peer-base
    environment:
      - CORE_PEER_ID=peer1.org1.example.com
      - CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=peer1.org1.example.com:8051
      - CORE_PEER_LISTENADDRESS=0.0.0.0:8051
      - CORE_PEER_CHAINCODEADDRESS=peer1.org1.example.com:8052
      - CORE_PEER_CHAINCODELISTENADDRESS=0.0.0.0:8052
      - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_EXTERNALENDPOINT=peer1.org1.example.com:8051
      - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_BOOTSTRAP=peer0.org1.example.com:7051
      - CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=Org1MSP
    volumes:
        - /var/run/:/host/var/run/
        - ../crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer1.org1.example.com/msp:/etc/hyperledger/fabric/msp
        - ../crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer1.org1.example.com/tls:/etc/hyperledger/fabric/tls
        - peer1.org1.example.com:/var/hyperledger/production
    ports:
      - 8051:8051

  peer0.org2.example.com:
    container_name: peer0.org2.example.com
    extends:
      file: peer-base.yaml
      service: peer-base
    environment:
      - CORE_PEER_ID=peer0.org2.example.com
      - CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=peer0.org2.example.com:7051
      - CORE_PEER_LISTENADDRESS=0.0.0.0:7051
      - CORE_PEER_CHAINCODEADDRESS=peer0.org2.example.com:7052
      - CORE_PEER_CHAINCODELISTENADDRESS=0.0.0.0:7052
      - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_EXTERNALENDPOINT=peer0.org2.example.com:7051
      - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_BOOTSTRAP=peer1.org2.example.com:10051
      - CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=Org2MSP
    volumes:
        - /var/run/:/host/var/run/
        - ../crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org2.example.com/peers/peer0.org2.example.com/msp:/etc/hyperledger/fabric/msp
        - ../crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org2.example.com/peers/peer0.org2.example.com/tls:/etc/hyperledger/fabric/tls
        - peer0.org2.example.com:/var/hyperledger/production
    ports:
      - 7051:7051

  peer1.org2.example.com:
    container_name: peer1.org2.example.com
    extends:
      file: peer-base.yaml
      service: peer-base
    environment:
      - CORE_PEER_ID=peer1.org2.example.com
      - CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=peer1.org2.example.com:10051
      - CORE_PEER_LISTENADDRESS=0.0.0.0:10051
      - CORE_PEER_CHAINCODEADDRESS=peer1.org2.example.com:10052
      - CORE_PEER_CHAINCODELISTENADDRESS=0.0.0.0:10052
      - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_EXTERNALENDPOINT=peer1.org2.example.com:10051
      - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_BOOTSTRAP=peer0.org2.example.com:7051
      - CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=Org2MSP
    volumes:
        - /var/run/:/host/var/run/
        - ../crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org2.example.com/peers/peer1.org2.example.com/msp:/etc/hyperledger/fabric/msp
        - ../crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org2.example.com/peers/peer1.org2.example.com/tls:/etc/hyperledger/fabric/tls
        - peer1.org2.example.com:/var/hyperledger/production
    ports:
      - 10051:10051
```

10.100.251.218.yaml

```
version: '2'

volumes:
  orderer.example.com:
  orderer5.example.com:
  peer0.org1.example.com:
  orderer2.example.com:
  peer1.org1.example.com:

networks:
  byfn:
    external:
      name: first-network

services:

  orderer.example.com:
    extends:
      file:   base/docker-compose-base.yaml
      service: orderer.example.com
    container_name: orderer.example.com
    networks:
      - byfn

  orderer5.example.com:
    extends:
      file:   base/peer-base.yaml
      service: orderer-base
    container_name: orderer5.example.com
    networks:
      - byfn
    volumes:
        - ./channel-artifacts/genesis.block:/var/hyperledger/orderer/orderer.genesis.block
        - ./crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer5.example.com/msp:/var/hyperledger/orderer/msp
        - ./crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer5.example.com/tls/:/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls
        - orderer5.example.com:/var/hyperledger/production/orderer
    ports:
      - 8050:7050
  couchdb0:
    container_name: couchdb0
    image: hyperledger/fabric-couchdb
    # Populate the COUCHDB_USER and COUCHDB_PASSWORD to set an admin user and password
    # for CouchDB.  This will prevent CouchDB from operating in an "Admin Party" mode.
    environment:
      - COUCHDB_USER=
      - COUCHDB_PASSWORD=
    # Comment/Uncomment the port mapping if you want to hide/expose the CouchDB service,
    # for example map it to utilize Fauxton User Interface in dev environments.
    volumes:
       - ./couchdb0/data:/opt/couchdb/data
    ports:
      - "5984:5984"
    networks:
      - byfn


  peer0.org1.example.com:
    container_name: peer0.org1.example.com
    extends:
      file:  base/docker-compose-base.yaml
      service: peer0.org1.example.com
    environment:
      - CORE_LEDGER_STATE_STATEDATABASE=CouchDB
      - CORE_LEDGER_STATE_COUCHDBCONFIG_COUCHDBADDRESS=couchdb0:5984
      # The CORE_LEDGER_STATE_COUCHDBCONFIG_USERNAME and CORE_LEDGER_STATE_COUCHDBCONFIG_PASSWORD
      # provide the credentials for ledger to connect to CouchDB.  The username and password must
      # match the username and password set for the associated CouchDB.
      - CORE_LEDGER_STATE_COUCHDBCONFIG_USERNAME=
      - CORE_LEDGER_STATE_COUCHDBCONFIG_PASSWORD=
    depends_on:
      - couchdb0

    networks:
      - byfn
  ca0:
    image: hyperledger/fabric-ca:$IMAGE_TAG
    environment:
      - FABRIC_CA_HOME=/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server
      - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_CA_NAME=ca-org1
      - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_TLS_ENABLED=true
      - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_TLS_CERTFILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config/ca.org1.example.com-cert.pem
      - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_TLS_KEYFILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config/ace37fd4b475ac91aa276aeede6c69052837639ec786dffe541626ca095bfe0e_sk
      - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_PORT=7054
    ports:
      - "7054:7054"
    command: sh -c 'fabric-ca-server start --ca.certfile /etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config/ca.org1.example.com-cert.pem --ca.keyfile /etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config/ace37fd4b475ac91aa276aeede6c69052837639ec786dffe541626ca095bfe0e_sk -b admin:adminpw -d'
    volumes:
      - ./crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/ca/:/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config
    container_name: ca_peerOrg1
    networks:
      - byfn

  orderer2.example.com:
    extends:
      file:   base/peer-base.yaml
      service: orderer-base
    container_name: orderer2.example.com
    networks:
      - byfn
    volumes:
        - ./channel-artifacts/genesis.block:/var/hyperledger/orderer/orderer.genesis.block
        - ./crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer2.example.com/msp:/var/hyperledger/orderer/msp
        - ./crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer2.example.com/tls/:/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls
        - orderer2.example.com:/var/hyperledger/production/orderer
    ports:
      - 9050:7050
  couchdb1:
    container_name: couchdb1
    image: hyperledger/fabric-couchdb
    # Populate the COUCHDB_USER and COUCHDB_PASSWORD to set an admin user and password
    # for CouchDB.  This will prevent CouchDB from operating in an "Admin Party" mode.
    environment:
      - COUCHDB_USER=
      - COUCHDB_PASSWORD=
    # Comment/Uncomment the port mapping if you want to hide/expose the CouchDB service,
    # for example map it to utilize Fauxton User Interface in dev environments.
    volumes:
       - ./couchdb1/data:/opt/couchdb/data
    ports:
      - "6984:5984"
    networks:
      - byfn

  peer1.org1.example.com:
    container_name: peer1.org1.example.com
    extends:
      file:  base/docker-compose-base.yaml
      service: peer1.org1.example.com
    environment:
      - CORE_LEDGER_STATE_STATEDATABASE=CouchDB
      - CORE_LEDGER_STATE_COUCHDBCONFIG_COUCHDBADDRESS=couchdb1:5984
      # The CORE_LEDGER_STATE_COUCHDBCONFIG_USERNAME and CORE_LEDGER_STATE_COUCHDBCONFIG_PASSWORD
      # provide the credentials for ledger to connect to CouchDB.  The username and password must
      # match the username and password set for the associated CouchDB.
      - CORE_LEDGER_STATE_COUCHDBCONFIG_USERNAME=
      - CORE_LEDGER_STATE_COUCHDBCONFIG_PASSWORD=
    depends_on:
      - couchdb1

    networks:
      - byfn
  cli:
    container_name: cli
    image: hyperledger/fabric-tools:$IMAGE_TAG
    tty: true
    stdin_open: true
    environment:
      - SYS_CHANNEL=$SYS_CHANNEL
      - GOPATH=/opt/gopath
      - CORE_VM_ENDPOINT=unix:///host/var/run/docker.sock
      #- FABRIC_LOGGING_SPEC=DEBUG
      - FABRIC_LOGGING_SPEC=INFO
      - CORE_PEER_ID=cli
      - CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=peer0.org1.example.com:7051
      - CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=Org1MSP
      - CORE_PEER_TLS_ENABLED=true
      - CORE_PEER_TLS_CERT_FILE=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer0.org1.example.com/tls/server.crt
      - CORE_PEER_TLS_KEY_FILE=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer0.org1.example.com/tls/server.key
      - CORE_PEER_TLS_ROOTCERT_FILE=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer0.org1.example.com/tls/ca.crt
      - CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/users/Admin@org1.example.com/msp
    working_dir: /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer
    command: /bin/bash
    volumes:
        - /var/run/:/host/var/run/
        - ./../chaincode/:/opt/gopath/src/github.com/chaincode
        #- ./../Contract_XIoTv3_20200801/contract:/opt/gopath/src/github.com/chaincode
        - ./crypto-config:/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/
        - ./scripts:/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/scripts/
        - ./channel-artifacts:/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/channel-artifacts
    depends_on:
      - orderer.example.com
      - orderer5.example.com
      - peer0.org1.example.com
      - couchdb0
      - couchdb1
      - orderer2.example.com
      - peer1.org1.example.com
    networks:
      - byfn
```

10.100.251.219.yaml

```
version: '2'

volumes:
  orderer3.example.com:
  peer0.org2.example.com:
  orderer4.example.com:
  peer1.org2.example.com:

networks:
  byfn:
    external:
      name: first-network

services:
  orderer3.example.com:
    extends:
      file:   base/peer-base.yaml
      service: orderer-base
    container_name: orderer3.example.com
    networks:
      - byfn
    volumes:
        - ./channel-artifacts/genesis.block:/var/hyperledger/orderer/orderer.genesis.block
        - ./crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer3.example.com/msp:/var/hyperledger/orderer/msp
        - ./crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer3.example.com/tls/:/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls
        - orderer3.example.com:/var/hyperledger/production/orderer
    ports:
      - 7050:7050
  couchdb3:
    container_name: couchdb3
    image: hyperledger/fabric-couchdb
    # Populate the COUCHDB_USER and COUCHDB_PASSWORD to set an admin user and password
    # for CouchDB.  This will prevent CouchDB from operating in an "Admin Party" mode.
    environment:
      - COUCHDB_USER=
      - COUCHDB_PASSWORD=
    # Comment/Uncomment the port mapping if you want to hide/expose the CouchDB service,
    # for example map it to utilize Fauxton User Interface in dev environments.
    volumes:
       - ./couchdb3/data:/opt/couchdb/data
    ports:
      - "5984:5984"
    networks:
      - byfn

  peer0.org2.example.com:
    container_name: peer0.org2.example.com
    extends:
      file:  base/docker-compose-base.yaml
      service: peer0.org2.example.com
    environment:
      - CORE_LEDGER_STATE_STATEDATABASE=CouchDB
      - CORE_LEDGER_STATE_COUCHDBCONFIG_COUCHDBADDRESS=couchdb3:5984
      # The CORE_LEDGER_STATE_COUCHDBCONFIG_USERNAME and CORE_LEDGER_STATE_COUCHDBCONFIG_PASSWORD
      # provide the credentials for ledger to connect to CouchDB.  The username and password must
      # match the username and password set for the associated CouchDB.
      - CORE_LEDGER_STATE_COUCHDBCONFIG_USERNAME=
      - CORE_LEDGER_STATE_COUCHDBCONFIG_PASSWORD=
    depends_on:
      - couchdb3
    networks:
      - byfn
  ca1:
    image: hyperledger/fabric-ca:$IMAGE_TAG
    environment:
      - FABRIC_CA_HOME=/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server
      - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_CA_NAME=ca-org2
      - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_TLS_ENABLED=true
      - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_TLS_CERTFILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config/ca.org2.example.com-cert.pem
      - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_TLS_KEYFILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config/d3dad90df4ac9a4132c4794968fa36d8c80d4f57f9c72a58d950eb01c7050020_sk
      - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_PORT=7054
    ports:
      - "7054:7054"
    command: sh -c 'fabric-ca-server start --ca.certfile /etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config/ca.org2.example.com-cert.pem --ca.keyfile /etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config/d3dad90df4ac9a4132c4794968fa36d8c80d4f57f9c72a58d950eb01c7050020_sk -b admin:adminpw -d'
    volumes:
      - ./crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org2.example.com/ca/:/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config
    container_name: ca_peerOrg2
    networks:
      - byfn

  orderer4.example.com:
    extends:
      file:   base/peer-base.yaml
      service: orderer-base
    container_name: orderer4.example.com
    networks:
      - byfn
    volumes:
        - ./channel-artifacts/genesis.block:/var/hyperledger/orderer/orderer.genesis.block
        - ./crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer4.example.com/msp:/var/hyperledger/orderer/msp
        - ./crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer4.example.com/tls/:/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls
        - orderer4.example.com:/var/hyperledger/production/orderer
    ports:
      - 8050:7050
  couchdb4:
    container_name: couchdb4
    image: hyperledger/fabric-couchdb
    # Populate the COUCHDB_USER and COUCHDB_PASSWORD to set an admin user and password
    # for CouchDB.  This will prevent CouchDB from operating in an "Admin Party" mode.
    environment:
      - COUCHDB_USER=
      - COUCHDB_PASSWORD=
    # Comment/Uncomment the port mapping if you want to hide/expose the CouchDB service,
    # for example map it to utilize Fauxton User Interface in dev environments.
    volumes:
       - ./couchdb4/data:/opt/couchdb/data
    ports:
      - "6984:5984"
    networks:
      - byfn

  peer1.org2.example.com:
    container_name: peer1.org2.example.com
    extends:
      file:  base/docker-compose-base.yaml
      service: peer1.org2.example.com
    environment:
      - CORE_LEDGER_STATE_STATEDATABASE=CouchDB
      - CORE_LEDGER_STATE_COUCHDBCONFIG_COUCHDBADDRESS=couchdb4:5984
      # The CORE_LEDGER_STATE_COUCHDBCONFIG_USERNAME and CORE_LEDGER_STATE_COUCHDBCONFIG_PASSWORD
      # provide the credentials for ledger to connect to CouchDB.  The username and password must
      # match the username and password set for the associated CouchDB.
      - CORE_LEDGER_STATE_COUCHDBCONFIG_USERNAME=
      - CORE_LEDGER_STATE_COUCHDBCONFIG_PASSWORD=
    depends_on:
      - couchdb4
    networks:
      - byfn
  cli:
    container_name: cli
    image: hyperledger/fabric-tools:$IMAGE_TAG
    tty: true
    stdin_open: true
    environment:
      - SYS_CHANNEL=$SYS_CHANNEL
      - GOPATH=/opt/gopath
      - CORE_VM_ENDPOINT=unix:///host/var/run/docker.sock
      #- FABRIC_LOGGING_SPEC=DEBUG
      - FABRIC_LOGGING_SPEC=INFO
      - CORE_PEER_ID=cli
      - CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=peer0.org2.example.com:7051
      - CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=Org2MSP
      - CORE_PEER_TLS_ENABLED=true
      - CORE_PEER_TLS_CERT_FILE=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org2.example.com/peers/peer0.org2.example.com/tls/server.crt
      - CORE_PEER_TLS_KEY_FILE=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org2.example.com/peers/peer0.org2.example.com/tls/server.key
      - CORE_PEER_TLS_ROOTCERT_FILE=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org2.example.com/peers/peer0.org2.example.com/tls/ca.crt
      - CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org2.example.com/users/Admin@org2.example.com/msp
    working_dir: /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer
    command: /bin/bash
    volumes:
        - /var/run/:/host/var/run/
        - ./../chaincode/:/opt/gopath/src/github.com/chaincode
        - ./crypto-config:/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/
        - ./scripts:/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/scripts/
        - ./channel-artifacts:/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/channel-artifacts
    depends_on:
      - orderer3.example.com
      - peer0.org2.example.com
      - couchdb3
      - orderer4.example.com
      - peer1.org2.example.com
      - couchdb4
    networks:
      - byfn
```

Answer (score 0):

I have packaged chaincode with package-lock.json which is generated by mac,
and instantiate chaincode in ubuntu platform, network timeout happens.

when I delete the package-lock.json, Instantiating chaincode can succeed.

I use fabric v1.4.6.

According to https://docs.npmjs.com/configuring-npm/package-lock-json.html

> One key detail about package-lock.json is that it cannot be published.

Comment: how to build chaincode image lead to network timeout because package-lock.json?who can explain it?
network timeout lead me to low network band.